# Separar dados dentro de coluna e colocar em novas linhas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Eu tenho um data frame como:

```
df = {'Column1': ['A, B, C', 'D', 'E, F'], 'Column2': [3, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

que aparece como:

```
Column1        Column2
A, B, C           3
   D              2
  E, F            4
```

Preciso manipular para que ele crie uma nova linha a cada virgula na coluna 1, pois ele representa mais de um dado. Ficaria dessa forma:

```
Column1        Column2
  A              3
  B              3
  C              3
  D              2
  E              4
  F              4
```

Qual comando preciso dar?

Comment: olá este é o site do SO em português, traduza sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você converte a string na coluna **Column1** para um array com `split` e depois utiliza o comando `explode` para expandir os dados da forma que você deseja

```
df = df.assign(Column1 = df['Column1'].str.split(',')).explode('Column1')
df.head(10)
#saida
    Column1 Column2
0   A       3
0   B       3
0   C       3
1   D       2
2   E       4
2   F       4
```